# Bootstrap Input Spinner only shows on reloading page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, spinner

I use this HTML:

```
<input id='year_input' class='' type='number' value='5' min='0' max='10' step='1'/>
```

And this Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#year_input").inputSpinner({
        buttonsClass: "spinner_buttons",
        buttonsOnly: true,
      });
    });
    </script>
```

It only shows the spinner when I reload the page.
I don't know what to do...

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: In what order do you add your js files? It works. I just tested but used https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-input-spinner@3.0.2/src/bootstrap-input-spinner.min.js instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/1gkLahrb/

Comment: I think I have found the issue, and is related to the ajax enable pages that do not load the scripts on load. I thank you for your help.